# Error resolving hostname after restart network interface

Tags: networking, services

I have many services on my Linux server where it uses the `gethostbyname` API/Service to retrieve the IP address of some `hostname` .

When I tried to use `ifdown`/`ifup` these services throws errors shows that the `hostname` are unknown and I should restart the services to resolve the issue

I know that if I put IP addresses in the `/etc/hosts` this problem will be solved.

However I would like to have other solution than restart the services or put the IP addresses in the hosts file.

Comment: Please show `cat /etc/hosts` and `cat /etc/hostname`.